# Speedier File Access in Window Manager/File Explorer when File Names have Similar Starts

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, xorg

I was wondering both from a Windows [7] and a GNU-Linux system set-up perspective:

When you are opening files in the File Explorer/Window Manager and you type in the first letters in the file's name to select that folder, I was wondering about this situation. You have a series of files with the start of the file name. For example:

```
DocFolder
Doc1.odt
Doc2.doc
Doc5.txt
```

Is there a way of implementing a system where you can type in `F` to get `DocFolder` or a `5` to get Doc5.txt. Or even say in the following situation:

```
DocFolder
Doc1.odt
Doc2.doc
Doc5.txt
Folder1
Song.ogg
```

You could type `DF` for DocFolder or `D5` for Doc5.

Can this be implemented some way or is there another way of doing it. I largely navigate through files using my keyboard and was wondering if there was any other way of doing this. Or is this one for the source code [assuming you use an operating system decent enough to provide this].

Comment: I'm looking into it, if you don't mind building KDE from source. It appears you could change the `KUrlNavigator` class to do what you want.

Comment: So it appears you could add this functionality to all `qt` based applications by changing the code in `QUrl` around line 4930 - the `queryItemValue` and `encodedQueryItemValue` functions. I found the source code [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/7853af34ec991a1ff2d0b23f09439d34663e47b1:src/corelib/io/qurl.cpp#L4684).

Comment: Any add-ons for Windows that any one has heard of either? Thanks for the comments thus far!

Comment: [I got a bad gateway [502] on the qt link as well sorry]

Comment: It is working for me, try [this](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/4.5:src/corelib/io/qurl.cpp) link.

Comment: You could try [listary](http://www.listary.com/download) which is an addon for windows. It does both of what you mentioned above. I haven't used it though, just found it on my feeds list.